# NSMutableArray memory leaks problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm working on simple iPhone game. When a game finish i'm trying to save some scores info to a .plist file. Can you help me to understand what i'm doing wrong?

Here is method for a "Done" game:

```
- (void) gameDone {

    // something ....

// save our current score values
NSDictionary *currentScore = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[score getScoreValue]], @"score", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[time getSeconds]], @"time", nil];
[score saveValueToFile:currentScore toFile:fileName];
[currentScore release];

// something ....
```

}

Here is 2 methods to save a scores from my other class:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) loadFromFile:(NSString *) fileName {
{
    // get a paths
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", fileName]];

    NSMutableArray *scoreTable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    return scoreTable;
}


// save a score table to plist file
- (void) saveValueToFile:(NSDictionary *)value toFile:(NSString *)fileName {

    // load all score table
    NSMutableArray *scoreTable;
    scoreTable = [self loadFromFile:fileName];

    // insert new value
        // [MEMORY_LEAKS_LINE] ATTENTION: Instrument > Memory Leaks point to this line  
    [scoreTable insertObject:value atIndex:[scoreTable count]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", fileName]];

    [scoreTable writeToFile:path atomically:YES];   
    [scoreTable release];   
}
```

When I launch a new game (actually my game designed with possibility to play many games one after another) Memory Leaks Instrument always add 32 bytes to Total Leaks Bytes and link to [MEMORY_LEAKS_LINE]

I thought my problem might be with currentScore value. But I release it in first part of sample code here.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried "Product->Analyze"

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about the leak, but you are doing 'scoreTable release' , but your scoreTable is already in autorelease mode (you called  [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]), so it's not retained

Comment: Ok, maybe my phrasing was incorrect - but the idea is - there is a double-release here, which is a no-no.

Comment: In any way double release will not alloc memory. Why i'm getting +32 bytes to my Memory Leaks Total?

Comment: You need to fix all the errors you know about before you go chasing leaks. This code wont even compile. Make sure you have zero warnings when you build and use the static analyzer.